# Get current hostname and push it into conf file with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, yaml

I'm working into an ansible playbook to get the current hostname of a server and then set it into a configuration file. I cannot figure it out how can I push the shell output using the lineinfile module.

```
  - name: Get hostname
    shell: echo $HOSTNAME
    register: result

  - name: Set hostname on conf file
    lineinfile: dest=/etc/teste/linux/zabbix_agentd.conf regexp="^Hostname=.*" insertafter="^# Hostname=" line=Hostname=????
```

Comment: You registered the output of `echo $HOSTNAME` as the variable `result`. Does `result` not contain the expected value?

Comment: It contains. The question is: how can I use its output?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general, to look what's inside a variable you can use the `debug` module.

```
- debug:
    var: result
```

This should show you an object and its properties which include `stdout`. That is the complete result of the previous command. So to use the output of the first task you would use `result.stdout`.

To use any variable you would use Jinja2 expressions: `{{ whatever }}`. So your task could look like this:

```
- name: Set hostname on conf file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/teste/linux/zabbix_agentd.conf
    regexp: ^Hostname=.*
    insertafter: ^# Hostname=
    line: Hostname={{ result.stdout }}
```

---

So much for theory, **but here comes the real answer**. Don't do it like that. Of course Ansible already knows the hostname.

The hostname as defined in your inventory would be `{{ inventory_hostname }}`. The hostname as reported by the server is `{{ ansible_hostname }}`. Additionally there is `{{ ansible_fqdn }}`. So just use any of these instead of running an additional task:

```
- name: Set hostname on conf file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/teste/linux/zabbix_agentd.conf
    regexp: ^Hostname=.*
    insertafter: ^# Hostname=
    line: Hostname={{ ansible_hostname }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [pass variables in the command line](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

First, register the variable

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
  - person: John Snow
  - filename: v1.j2
  vars_files:
  - vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: Who I am?
    action: command /usr/bin/whoami
    register: myname
  - name: Run jpprog.sh
    action: command ./jpprog.sh
    register: v

  - name: Populate template
    action: template src={{filename}} dest=/tmp/out
```

This playbook runs two commands: the first stores its output in a variable called myname, and the second in a variable v. The result of whoami is a single string which is made available to the template as variablename.stdout. The result of jpprog.sh is a JSON object represented as a string:

```
{
    "number": 18,
    "name": "john"
}
```

The template follows:

```
-> I am {{ myname.stdout }}

{% set t = v.stdout|from_json %}

JSON struct T: {{ t }}

name = {{ t.name }} 
number = {{ t['number'] }}
```

and the output is:

```
-> I am jpm

JSON struct T: {u'number': 18, u'name': u'john'}

name = john 
number = 18
```

Source:[Jan-Piet Mens web site](http://jpmens.net/2012/08/30/ansible-variables-variables-and-more-variables/).

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: Set hostname on conf file
  command: sed -i s/whatComesAfterHostname=/{{ ansible_hostname }}/g /etc/teste/linux/zabbix_agentd.conf
```

worked for me.